# Glidejs is not loading on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, glidejs

I'm trying to add glidejs to a wordpress site, it's working perfectly on desktop, but on mobile, it's not loading, seems that the JS files aren't being executed. I don't see a single error in the console. [This the codepen](https://codepen.io/usmonovsardor7770/pen/WEqjMa). On mobile I see 3 pictures on top of each other.

the template

```
<section id="Glide" class="glide banner_desktop">

    <!-- ARROWS -->
      <div class="glide__arrows">
        <button class="glide__arrow prev" data-glide-dir="<"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
        <button class="glide__arrow next" data-glide-dir=">"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
      </div>

     <div class="glide__wrapper">
        <ul class="glide__track">

<?php if ( have_rows( 'banner_desktop', 'option' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'banner_desktop', 'option' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'image' ) ) { ?>

          <li class="glide__slide">

    <a href="<?php the_sub_field( 'link' ); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php the_sub_field( 'image' );?>" />
                </a>                
                </li>

        <?php
    }
         endwhile; endif;
         ?>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- CAROUSEL DOTS -->
      <div class="glide__bullets"></div>

</section>
```

functions.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'glide', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/glide/glide.js', array('jQuery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'glide_Js', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/glide/glide_JS.js', array('jQuery') );

wp_enqueue_style( 'glide_css', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/glide/glide.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'glide_theme', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/glide/glide_theme.css');
```

glide.js is

```
var glide = function () {
// glide.min.js code which is on codepen 
//   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glidejs@2/dist/glide.min.js 
}();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create a **glide** folder at the root of your theme, same level as `style.css`
2- In this folder put `glide.min.js`, `glide.core.css`, `glide.theme.css` and Create `my.glide.js`
3- In functions.php of your theme add :

```
/**
 * Enqueue Glide.js scripts and styles.
 */
function glide_js_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'glide-core', get_theme_file_uri( '/glide/glide.core.css' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/glide/glide.core.css' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'glide-theme', get_theme_file_uri( '/glide/glide.theme.css' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/glide/glide.theme.css' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'glide', get_theme_file_uri( '/glide/glide.min.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/glide/glide.min.js' ) ), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-glide', get_theme_file_uri( '/glide/my.glide.js' ), array('jquery'), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/glide/my.glide.js' ) ), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'glide_js_scripts_styles' );
```

Since Glide has no dependency, you leave the dependency `array()` empty for `glide.min.js`, but you add it to you personal one `my.glide.js`
4- In your `my.glide.js`, fire the script :

```
(function ($) {
    new Glide('.glide', {
        type: 'carousel',
        startAt: 0,
        perView: 3
    });

    // OR

    $('.glide').glide({
        type: 'carousel',
        startAt: 0,
        perView: 3
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Please, note that **you should use a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)** for your customization or all your changes will be removed in the next update of the theme that you are using.
So use a child theme and make the same steps in the child theme.

Comment: Thanks for answering my fellow Lebanese :) Once in a lifetime I encounter people from my country here. Should I use the latest version of glide? I'm using 2.x, strangely 3.x didn't work at all, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'll test your answer tomorrow and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Hello :) Generally speaking, it's better to use the last build of a script. You where not correctly calling the files. Their is no `jQuery` handle dependency in [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) but a `jquery` one. And some script are dependency free, so we leave the `array()` empty. Finally, always refer to the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) you'll find in depth documentation, best practice of use and examples. Please, let me know when you try :)